# DAX calculate values for each subgroup without applied values filters

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I have a pivot table with 2 slicers to manage population (Morning/Afternoon; Visit type), 3 subgroups with ID and Names as rows and 3 calculated measures as columns:
1. Basic count formula:
 `=COUNTROWS(Visit)`
2. Long Median formula:

```
=(MINX (FILTER (VALUES (Visit[Colum1]),  
  CALCULATE (COUNT (Visit[Colum1]), Visit[Colum1]   
<= EARLIER (Visit[Colum1])) > COUNT ( Visit[Colum1]) / 2), Visit[Colum1]...
```

3. Lookup/SUM formula:
`=IF(CALCULATE(SUM(PE_new[DenominatorNBR2]), RELATEDTABLE(Visit)) < 30, BLANK(),
CALCULATE(SUM(PE_new[NumeratorNBR2]), RELATEDTABLE(Visit)) / 
CALCULATE(SUM(PE_new[DenominatorNBR2]), RELATEDTABLE(Visit)))`

The problem I'm trying to find a solution to is to show only rows with values that are equal or greater than 10 in the column C (Measure 1 (Sum)).
I can do that using "values filters" for ID or Names columns but in this case subtotals will be changing as well (decreasing the number of records) but I need to show subtotals for each group as a whole, not only calculations for those rows with more than 10 values.

Is there a way to write/change a DAX formula for subtotals where it will calculate values for the whole group, not taking into account "values filters"?
Or maybe there are other options to show only rows with values that are equal or greater than 10 but calculate values for the whole group in subtotals?

Will be grateful for any help!

This is original table:

[image]

This is what I get now (subtotals are based on the current/filtered pivot records: values that are equal or greater than 10 in the column C (Measure 1 (Sum))):

[image]

Looking for this result (subtotals are shown for each group as a whole):

[image]

A screenshot with a "values filters" filter:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your measure to calculate differently depending on whether it is a subtotal or not using functions like `HASONEVALUE` of `ISFILTERED`. So if you've used "values filters" to limit which rows you see, you can still get subtotals including all rows by using the appropriate filter context.

E.g., for a basic count, you could write something like this

```
CountMeasure = 
IF(HASONEVALUE(Visit[ID]),
    COUNT(Visit[Column1]),
    CALCULATE(COUNT(Visit[Column1]), ALLEXCEPT(Visit, Visit[Group]))
)
```

The `ALLEXCEPT` function removes all of the filter context except for the column(s) you specify. The same pattern should work for other measures as well:

```
SubtotalMeasure = 
IF(HASONEVALUE(Visit[ID]),
    [Measure],
    CALCULATE([Measure], ALLEXCEPT(Visit, Visit[Group]))
)
```

---

**Edit:** In response to your comments, it's a bit tricky to get separate slicer selections from value filtering since the DAX measure treats them similarly. However, if they are slicing/filtering on different columns, then it should be possible.

For example, if you had a slicer on `ID`, then you could pass that column into your `ALLEXCEPT` function as another argument: `ALLEXCEPT(Visit, Visit[Group], Visit[ID])`. This would prevent it from removing the slicer filtering on `ID`.

The standard way to remove filter context while preserving slicer selections is using `ALLSELECTED`. However, this would preserve the values filtering as well.

You might be able to get the particular filter context you want using a combination of these sorts of this. For example,

```
SubtotalMeasure =
VAR CurrentGroup = MAX(Visit[Group])
RETURN
IF(HASONEVALUE(Visit[ID]),
    [Measure],
    CALCULATE([Measure],
        ALLSELECTED(Visit),
        ALL(Visit[Name]),
        Visit[Group] = CurrentGroup
    )
)
```

The would combine all those arguments in an `AND` fashion. The `ALLSELECTED(Visit)` would keep all the slicer and value filtering (but not the pivot table context), the `ALL(Visit[Name])` would remove the value filtering on the `Name` column (but also any slicer selections on that column), and `Visit[Group]` would set the filter context for the `Group` column to be only the `Group` value for the current row in the current table that is defined by the variable above.

I can't guarantee that this particular combination will work for your particular setup since I don't know what all columns and slicers and so forth you have, but it should give you an idea of what sort of things you can try.

Comment: Thank you @Alexis Olson. It worked, I managed to remove all filters from subtotals but now all my slicers' selections do not work as well and I always get a count for total population for each group no matter if I use slicer or not. Is there a way to remove only one "values filters" filter (greater than or equal to..) and leave all slicers' selection accountable? I attached to the post a screenshot with "values filters" filter I'm using.

Comment: Thank you @Alexis Olson. It worked, I managed to remove all filters from subtotals but now all my slicers' selections do not work as well and I always get a count for total population for each group no matter if I use slicers or not. Is there a way to remove only one "values filters" filter (greater than or equal to..) and leave all slicers' selection accountable? The idea is to only not show IDs with less than 30 counts (count them in subtotals) but have subtotals change based on slicers selection (to get different populations). I attached a screenshot with "values filters" filter I'm using.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot @Alexis Olson! I used your first suggestion by adding columns into ALLEXCEPT function and it worked great! The only thing I didn't figure out how to use your last formula with VAR to created a measure. I always get this error: "The calculated field formula must start with an equals sign" or "The syntax for 'CurrentGroup' is incorrect"...

Comment: You must have an older version that doesn't allow variables.